# Как через ajax передать изображение в виде массива байтов на сервер?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Работаю с asp.net и мне нужно передать изображение как массив байтов на сервер, т.е. модель имеет следующий вид:

```
public long Id { get; set; }
public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
```

Далее я пытаюсь передать изображение в виде массива байтов, но не получается. Последние попытки закончились этим кодом:

```
let formData = new FormData();
    let file = document.getElementById($('#upload-avatar').prop('id')).files[0];
    formData.append("Avatar", file);
    formData.append("Id", @Model.User.Id);

    console.log(formData.get("Avatar"))
    console.log(formData.get("Id"))
    

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UploadProfileImage", "Account")',
        method: 'post',
        data: formData,
        contentType: 'false',
        processData: false,
        success: (response) => {
            alert("Success");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: (response) => {
            alert("Error");
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
    .done(() => {
        alert("Done")
        formData.delete("Avatar")
        formData.delete("Id")
    })
    .fail(() => {
        alert("Fail")
        formData.delete("Avatar")
        formData.delete("Id")
    })
```

Но в таком случае я не сервере получаю Avatar как null, но Id "доставляется" нормально

На сколько я понял, мне нужно как-то адекватно конвертировать изображение в массив байтов перед отправкой, но я не могу понять, как это мне сделать.

UPD: так же мне не нужно реализация через canvas, т.к. canvas это

> это HTML элемент, использующийся для рисования графики средствами языков программирования (обычно это JavaScript)

Мне нужно изображение конвертировать прям перед отправкой, а не рисовать его. 90% статей делают реализацию через canvas, что для меня является просто бредом, т.к. это не подходит по тему конвертирования вообще.

Comment: Возможно эта [статья вам поможет](https://learn.javascript.ru/blob)

Comment: @SwaD, к сожалению, всё что я нашёл это "Изображение в Blob", которое не очень подходит, т.к. там используется canvas, чего-то более практичного тоже не нашёл, но всё равно спасибо вам

Comment: @Faraday по-моему вы не совсем верно статью поняли, там есть ответы на ваши вопросы